# Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку с ботом для телеграмма!

Tags: бот, telegram

Как только я закончил писать бота, конечно же я его запустил всё было правильно, но тут мне дается ошибка такая:

`AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'`

И что делать я не знаю! Весь гугл пересмотрел, но ответа так и не нашёл, я пробовал всё что мне предлагали, но ничего не помогало!
Что делать я не знаю.
Код в котором ошибка:

````
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Чтобы посмеятся введите любую цифру:')```

Ошибка:```AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код может покажете? или гадать на кофейной гуще?))

Comment: Для начала надо поместить сюда свой скрипт.

Comment: Картинкой - не пойдет, читать не удобно, проверить не выйдет... =) так что будьте любезны ознакомьтесь с правилами сайта https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

(естественно ключи выкладывать НЕ нужно)

Comment: Очень похоже что проблема у вас с библиотекой бота попробуйте обновить с гита

Comment: Как мне обновить её с гита?

Comment: Зайти на сайт, и прочитать документацию https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
pip3 uninstall telebot 
pip3 install pytelegrambotapi --upgrade
```

Comment: Не помогает.000

Comment: попробуй переустановить пакеты, либо установить версию пониже pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI==2.2.3

Comment: Не работает. Всё что вы мне предлагаете я уже пробовал.